# How to accept Android license in macOS Terminal?

Tags: terminal, install, android, license

I'm trying to install some Android tools via the macOS terminal, but I can't get any further with the license confirmation. I feel a bit stupid - but can someone please tell me **what I'm doing wrong?**

The question in terminal:

> Accept? (y/N): ./avdmanager -v create avd -n x86 -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86" -g "google_apis"y

The result:

> Accept? (y/N): ./avdmanager -v create avd -n x86 -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86" -g "google_apis"y Skipping following packages as the license is not accepted: Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3 SDK Patch Applier v4 Android SDK Platform-Tools Android SDK Platform 25 Android Emulator The following packages can not be installed since their licenses or those of the packages they depend on were not accepted: patcher;v4 emulator platforms;android-25  platform-tools  build-tools;25.0.3 system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86
>
> [=======================================] 100% Computing updates...

Comment: It seems you type `./avdmanager -v create avd -n x86 -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86" -g "google_apis"y` instead of just `y`? But it would be odd to do that.

Comment: Can you please fix the line breaks in your output? Right now it's rather confusing (I'm quite sure that not everything is on one line). Also there probably is some text *before* the "Accept" which might be helpful.

Comment: Just a thought: Your keyboard *does* send a "y" to Terminal if you press "y" (and not a "z" for instance)?

Comment: What's the script you are running? If there's any bug in it, should share the nearby source lines, if you can identify them.